# compiz config settings manager how to operate an enable

Tags: ccsm

does anyone know of any links that i could refference so as to learn how to use COMPIZ more effectively as far as the features go an how to enable an operate them ??

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best resource would be:

http://wiki.compiz.org/ (index with links)

It can be taken as official documentation...

Some links from the site you might find useful.

- http://wiki.compiz.org/CompizPlugins
- http://wiki.compiz.org/CompizFusionPlugins
- http://wiki.compiz.org/GeneralOptions

*Also Youtube has tons of videos about Compiz usage.*

Comment: TYVM .... greatly appreciated